# Db fields validation client side

Tags: java, jquery, oracle, hibernate, spring-mvc

I would like to automate client side data validation for my application that uses SpringMVC and Hibernate, specially in case of referential integrity constraint violation. A simple version of the structure of my application follows:

**DB**

I have an oracle db with some tables, let's take for example

a table `DOCUMENT` with an integer primary key `DOC_KEY` and a `TITLE` field 
a table `PAGE` with a foreign key `FK_DOCUMENT_ID`, a key `PAG_KEY` and a text "TEXT" field.

**ORM/application layer**

I have two (hibernate) entities(`Document` and `Page`) mapping those tables. To create a `Page` you need to create a `Document` before, it is not possible to create a `Page` without specifying the related `DOC_KEY` in the foreign key field.

**Web layer**

I created a form that allows the user to create a new document with some pages. He can insert a title for the document and one or more pages. Trying to create the `Page` object without specifying the `Document` title results in a DB error because no document is specified for the pages.

**Example use case**

The user tries to create a page setting its contents without specifying a document title. The client side validator marks the title field in red asking the user to fill it.

**Question**

Is it possible to automatically generate client side validation rules to avoid a server side call in case the Entity/Object/row I'm trying to insert doesn't satisfy the FK integrity rule check?

OR Are there any tools that allow a client side validation tool to "understand" foreign keys consistency?

I tried with jquery but wasn't able to find a way to automatically check foreign keys consistency.

**EDIT:**
**Notes on accepted answer**
Of course there is no way to know the state of the db client side without querying it or caching it client side, but that knowledge is necessary to check if a key exists and an integrity constraint is satisfied. My accepted answer matches the focus of the question.
I should have thought about it before

Comment: I think the feature you are looking for is sitting in SpringSource's Jira in ["unresolved" status.](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6453)

Comment: D'oh... the problem arises when you have lots of db tables mapped 1:1 on form elements on the web: you put an effort in defining db architecture to make everything consistent and correct but you can't use it client side, you need to replicate such logic...

Comment: Are you free to choose which technology you use in the web layer?

Comment: Yes but we must not pay for it.

Comment: why do you need to duplicate the logic that's already in the db?  Why not let the db throw the exceptions and then format the wording to the end user on the front end?

Comment: to avoid wasting electricity, bandwidth AND the user patience in letting the client, the server and the db talk while the validation could be done just clientside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to automatically generate client side validation rules
>   to avoid a server side call in case the Entity/Object/row I'm trying
>   to insert doesn't satisfy the FK integrity rule check?

**The Answer is a no..!!**

The database can be set with the different foreign key relations mapping and its integrity can be maintained by specifying the Foreign key relations in the mapping class. But the hibernate does not do anything in the front end.!!

You can do [validations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html_single/#d0e158) using the hibernate annotations.But that can only be done in the back end. 
**Hibernate does not deal with the front end.!!**

I understand the requirement that you have, but hibernate is not a front end tool. I suggest, any Operations related to DB communication must stay in the back end, else it makes an entry point to security freaks. ***Better keep it behind the service layer.***

Comment: I just want to replicate the db validation logic client side, no need to open anything up, the best scenario is to leave my server side application unmodified and to add something client side which validates input fields even while the server is stopped

Comment: @Gabber yes that's the what i have said, keep the validations in the front end using JavaScript etc. you can't make hibernate do the validations in the front end..!!

Comment: In fact I'm not asking for a way to let Hibernate do the validation client side, I'm asking if there is some way to _generate_ a new system to replicate the validation client side. I it _is_ possible to replicate the server validation rules client side, I just need to know if there is a tool which automates the job

Comment: @Gabber i dont find any tools to replicate the validations but, i believe there wont be any tools for that because, validations in tables cannot be controlled by anything from just front end. If a tool exist then it must be able to manage both front end and back end at the same time. rit..!!

Answer (score 1):

If you declare you database rules on the hibernate entities (what I would recommend), you might want to check the [JSR303JS](https://kenai.com/projects/jsr303js/pages/Home) project. I haven't used it myself and it doesn't seem to be very active, but it should give you an idea how you could implement to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to check if the document is created earlier and this you have to save it in some global object of js and then check for page. If both has the data then go for insertion. You can achieve this using jquery.